# How do I completely disable IPv6 on my router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ipv6

I'm having [some issues on many devices on my network](https://superuser.com/questions/1007444/ipv6-connection-fails-on-chrome-timeouts-on-firefox), that might be IPv6 related. **In order to troubleshoot it, I want to entirely disable IPv6 on the router itself**.

I'm using a Technicolor TD5130v2 as modem/router/ap. [Its manual](http://setuprouter.com/router/technicolor/td5130/manual-1247.pdf) doesn't seem to cover IPv6 except for a brief mention on "*Supports IPv4 and IPv6 protocols*" on the features page. The interface screenshots on the manual differ from the actual interface on my router, despite it visually being the same; I suspect it uses a custom firmware for my ISP. This suspicion is even stronger because (1) when installed, it enabled a hidden SSID called " WiFi", (2) it says "_FW_v17" on the start page, (3) I can browse to `http://192.168.1.1/wizard<isp-name>`. I have tried to apply [the latest firmware](http://www.speedtouch.com.br/td5130.htm) available, but the router rejects it with a "wrong file format" message.

I have tried to find the IPv6 settings and disable it anyway. On the admin interface, however, when I perform a "[ping to the all routers link-local address](https://superuser.com/a/242105/165442)", I still get a response from my router.

Here's the output of `ip -6 addr` and `ip -6 route`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::3e77:e6ff:XXXX:XXXX/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ip -6 route
fe80::/64 dev wlan0  proto kernel  metric 256 
default dev wlan0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 86333sec
default via fe80::9e97:26ff:XXXX:XXXX dev wlan0  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 233sec
```

I have disabled every "IPv6" setting I could find (see pictures below):

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think it would be good enough to disable DHCPv6 and Router Advertisements. Devices having LL addresses is a non-issue, because they also exist in “IPv4-only” environments.

Comment: @DanielB How do I achieve this on a TD5130v2?

Comment: Dunno, you probably already did, [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0equC.png). Just check any computer’s routing table. If a IPv6 default route isn’t there, the router isn’t advertising itself.

Comment: @DanielB There's a default IPv6 route. I've added the output of `ip -6 addr` and `ip -6 route` to the question.

Comment: Did you power cycle both the router and all devices/PCs?

Comment: @DanielB Yes, I did.

Comment: Connect to it with telnet and then enter the command ":ip ifconfig intf=LocalNetwork ipv6=disabled"

Answer (score 0):

Desactivation should be done on ubuntu also.

have you tried editing /etc/sysctl.conf with .. ?

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

or follow instruction from [Same question on Ubuntu forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04) ?

And of course, same to be done on android device.

Comment: I'd prefer a way that could be done on the router and I'd not have to change the settings on every device

Answer (score -1):

To start off, you need to login to the router via Telnet. This is easily accomplished on a Linux based system with the telnet command:

```
telnet 192.168.1.254
```

*(replace this address with your router's address if it is incorrect, you may need to install telnet via your Linux system's package manager)*

Then, simply run the following commands to disable ipv6:

```
:ppp ifdetach intf Internet
:ppp ifconfig ipv6 disabled intf Internet
:ppp attach intf Internet
```

This is basically a reverse of the method described [here](https://sokratisg.net/2013/06/30/technicolor-tg582n-ipv6-configuration-for-forthnet-isp/). I can't test this because I do not have a router of the same type.

Comment: These are commands for the  TG582n, I own a TD5130v2. I was able to connect to telnet, but it accepts only two commands: `help` and `config`. The latter have no IPv6 settings.

Comment: What is the output of the help command?